# SOAP API extend idle time

Tags: soap-api, exception

I am running the following query

```
SELECT Id, ParentId, Name, ContentType, BodyLength, Body, OwnerId, CreatedDate, CreatedById, LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedById, SystemModstamp FROM Attachment
```

using query option in my Sandbox environment. The sandbox is similar to production where there are about 300k records. The usual query runs for about 4 hours. When I tried running this for a few more trials, there was data being returned but after a few hours, I get the following error:

```
com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: Failed to send request to https://cs7.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/33.0/00Xe0000008CuJl
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.send(SoapConnection.java:121)
    at com.sforce.soap.partner.PartnerConnection.queryMore(PartnerConnection.java:593)
    at sflayer.SOAPDataReader.queryAll(SOAPDataReader.java:277)
    at sflayer.SOAPDataReader.run(SOAPDataReader.java:87)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.fastRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.sforce.ws.parser.MXParser.fillBuf(MXParser.java:2962)
    at com.sforce.ws.parser.MXParser.more(MXParser.java:3014)
    at com.sforce.ws.parser.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1397)
    at com.sforce.ws.parser.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1111)
    at com.sforce.ws.parser.XmlInputStream.next(XmlInputStream.java:136)
    at com.sforce.ws.bind.XmlObject.loadAfterStartTag(XmlObject.java:282)
    at com.sforce.ws.bind.XmlObject.load(XmlObject.java:268)
    at com.sforce.ws.bind.XmlObject.loadAfterStartTag(XmlObject.java:286)
    at com.sforce.ws.bind.XmlObject.load(XmlObject.java:268)
    at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readSingle(TypeMapper.java:653)
    at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readArray(TypeMapper.java:553)
    at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readObject(TypeMapper.java:531)
    at com.sforce.soap.partner.QueryResult.loadFields(QueryResult.java:146)
    at com.sforce.soap.partner.QueryResult.load(QueryResult.java:130)
    at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readSingle(TypeMapper.java:653)
    at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readObject(TypeMapper.java:529)
    at com.sforce.soap.partner.QueryMoreResponse_element.loadFields(QueryMoreResponse_element.java:64)
    at com.sforce.soap.partner.QueryMoreResponse_element.load(QueryMoreResponse_element.java:56)
    at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readSingle(TypeMapper.java:653)
    at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readObject(TypeMapper.java:529)
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.bind(SoapConnection.java:174)
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.receive(SoapConnection.java:148)
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.send(SoapConnection.java:99)
    ... 6 more
```

SOAPDataReader.queryAll() is the method that runs the query to use query() SOAP call.

1. If this happens more frequently, how can I increase idle time?
2. What would be an optimal way to restart the connection and go back to the
   previous call from a programming perspective? I'd not prefer calling
   the same function `SOAPDataReader.queryAll()` inside the `catch(ConnectionException ce)`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this by building a retrying framework on the caller on this particular exception.
Used this [library](https://github.com/rholder/guava-retrying) for implementation. A sample snippet in Java would look like:

```
com.github.rholder.retry.Retryer<Object> retryer = RetryerBuilder.newBuilder().retryIfException(e ->
        {
            boolean retry = false;
            if (e instanceof ConnectionException)
            {
                if ((e instanceof ApiFault) || (StringUtils.contains(ExceptionUtils.getRootCauseMessage(e),
                        ExceptionCode.INVALID_SESSION_ID.toString())))
                    retry = false;
                else
                    retry = true;
            }
            return retry;
        }).build();
QueryResult result = (QueryResult) retryer
                .call(() -> soapConnection.queryMore("queryLocator"));
```